# Not Able to run telnet service on CentOS machine

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, telnet

When I try to run the `telnet` service on CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 it throws the following error:

```
service telnet restart 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart 
telnet.service Failed to restart telnet.service: Unit telnet.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

The telnet server version running on my machine:

```
rpm -qa | grep telnet 
telnet-0.17-59.el7.x86_64 
telnet-server-0.17-59.el7.x86_64
```

How can I successfully start the telnet service on my machine?

Comment: What's the command you used? Did you used root account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have telnet installed. You can install it with:

```
sudo yum install -y telnet
```

Comment: tried above given command..but still it doesnt work[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start telnet.socket
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable telnet.socket
[root@localhost ~]# service telnet restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  telnet.service
Failed to restart telnet.service: Unit telnet.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Comment: Why do you start the telnet.socket? You have to start the telnet.service. And please, please don't paste multiline output in a comment (and if you put it in your post, be so kind as to format things correctly).

Comment: i have already run the command you gave and it shows "Package 1:telnet-0.17-59.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version"

Comment: Try to run `yum reinstall telnet` and if that doesn't help `yum remove telnet` followed by `yum install telnet` (all with `sudo` if appropriate)

Comment: Their `rpm` output shows that package is already installed. You enable the socket activation because that replaces the xinetd functionality. [Example](https://dpaste.de/g5Ye).

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS 6:

```
service xinetd start
chkconfig telnet on
chkconfig xinetd on
```

On CentOS 7:

```
systemctl start telnet.socket
systemctl enable telnet.socket
```